# A beginner’s explanation for PCA on a multivariate time series

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, svd, time-series, principal-component-analysis

This is very much a beginner’s question.

Say you have a 10 dimensional vector for every day in a time series of 100 days. I was reading about using PCA to reduce this to a one dimensional time series.  If the time series is represented by a 10 by 100 matrix,  what are the exact mathematical steps to reduce it to a 1 by 100 time series?

Comment: Have you learnt the steps to convert a dataset of 10-dimensional observations to 1 Dimension using PCA? If not, see e.g. https://builtin.com/data-science/step-step-explanation-principal-component-analysis, or find similar pages by searching for things like "how does PCA work?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your mathematical background is, but in terms of matrices, you can do like this.

1. Call the $10\times 100$ matrix for $M$.
2. Now build a new matrix by subtracting the mean vector from each vector.
   $$M_{ml} = M - \mu$$
3. Now calculate $M_{ml} {M_{ml}} ^T$
4. Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this matrix. By the spectral theorem it will have an ON basis of eigenvectors. As a usual ON transformation you can write it like $T = ADA^{T}$
5. Now remove the rows of all the non-largest diagonal values in $D$ matrix. Call the modified matrix $D_m$
6. To get the 1x100 matrix multiply the matrix $M_{ml}$ by the modified $D_mA^T$
7. To project on the shrunken space we need to remove corresponding columns in $A$ matrix (same as the rows we removed in $5$)). Call the modified matrix $A_m$.

   Now your 1x100 matrix will be $(D_mA^T)M_{ml}$

   And your projection onto the space will be $A_m(D_mA^T)M_{ml}$

Comment: Thank you!  Just to be sure let me understand the dimensions at each step. $m=10, l=100$ for my example. Step 3 gives a 10 by 10 matrix. Is $T$ 1 by 10 after step 5 so in step 6 we do $T M_{ml}$to end up with a 1 by 100 matrix?

Comment: @fomin Ah, I forgot that part, I will add it.